# Use apply to segment time series pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, keras, time-series

I am feading time series into a Keras LSTM model and I have a desired input of shape (586075,30,8). The way I am doing it now is:

```
# DataFrame input shape
print(train_features.shape)
(586105, 8)

x_train = []
y_train = []
t_steps = 30
# Segmenting Data
for i in range(t_steps, train_features.shape[0]):
    x_train.append(train_features[i-t_steps:i,:] )#upper bound in slice excluded
    y_train.append(train_targets[i-1,:] ) 
x_train, y_train = np.array(x_train), np.array(y_train)

print(x_train.shape, y_train.shape)
(586075,30,8) (586075,8)
```

It's incredibly slow for large data sets and I know you aren't supposed to loop in pandas when it can be avoided. Is there a way to do this using apply or other more efficient methods with pandas or numpy?

The last column of the data is the fraction of the day.
I use this to mask the data so the last time step in each sample is between two times:

```
# Filter for Times between 9:30 and 13:00
mask = np.where((x_train[:,-1,-1] > .3958) & (x_train[:,-1,-1] < .541667))
x_train = x_train[mask,:,:][0]
y_train = y_train[mask,:][0]
```

It seems like this could be all done in one step, much more efficiently using apply or a data generator.

Comment: Hi JHall651,  I'm trying to understand the loop in the first section of code.  What is the purpose of this loop?  Are you defining the target and training data from a dataframe?  Happy to help just need clarification.

Comment: @DouglasPearson Yes, I am using a DataFrame that that has a continuous time series with 8 columns. Prior to the loop I seperate into train_features and the train_targets so train_targets is a continuous time series with class labels and train_features is the same length but with data features. The objective is to get samples of time series that are t_steps long.

Comment: Ok so you want an output of a 3D dataframe for x_train and the loop creates the y_train dataframe?  Or do you want the x_train and y_train to be broken into chunks of 30 rows?

Comment: Sorry, I'll clarify that train_features and train_targets are numpy arrays. Not sure if that makes a difference. The objective is: to have an array fed in with shape = (58105,8). Each row is a time observation. The output should be an array with 3 dimensions. Each i in new_array[i,:,:] should correspond to 30 rows of the original input array. So new_array[1,:,:] would be row 1-30 of train_features. new_array[2,:,:] would be rows 2-31 of train_features. It is not necessary to do both the train_features and train_targets at the same time as I could just use the proposed method once for each.

Comment: All good!   @Martin Valgur beat me to the punch!  His method should work.

Answer (score 2):

You can preallocate the output Numpy array and iterate over the smaller `t_steps` dimension to speed things up a bit. For-loops in Python are not nearly as bad if they are kept small.

```
def add_windowed_dim(arr, window_size):
    out = np.empty((window_size, arr.shape[0]-window_size, arr.shape[1]))        
    for i in range(window_size):                              
        out[i, :, :] = arr[i:-window_size+i, :]
    return np.rollaxis(out, 1)

x_train = add_windowed_dim(train_features, t_steps)
y_train = train_targets[t_steps-1:-1, :]
```

This improved the runtime from 1350 ms to 110 ms on a simulated dataset of the same size that you are using.

The second step looks fine to me. Its runtime was already relatively shorter at 77 ms.

Comment: Thank you for this response. I am trying to understand how this works. I noticed that the last row in the `train_features` does not appear as the last row for `x_train`. `x_train[-1,:,:] == train_features[-2,:]`.